# Как встроить ogre в qt5?

Tags: qt, qt5, ogre

Как встроить движок [огр](https://www.ogre3d.org/) в qt5  ??

Я нашёл пример в интернете , но так и не смог запустить .
Огр у меня версии libogre-1.12-dev

[Делал по шаблону](https://wiki.ogre3d.org/Integrating+Ogre+into+QT5)

Выдаёт мне вывод :

```
Запускается /home/dima/dima_project/ogre_example3/ogre_example3...
Creating resource group General
Creating resource group OgreInternal
Creating resource group OgreAutodetect
SceneManagerFactory for type 'DefaultSceneManager' registered.
Registering ResourceManager for type Material
Registering ResourceManager for type Mesh
Registering ResourceManager for type Skeleton
MovableObjectFactory for type 'ParticleSystem' registered.
ArchiveFactory for type 'FileSystem' registered
ArchiveFactory for type 'Zip' registered
ArchiveFactory for type 'EmbeddedZip' registered
DDS codec registering
ETC codec registering
ASTC codec registering
Registering ResourceManager for type HighLevelGpuProgram
Registering ResourceManager for type Compositor
MovableObjectFactory for type 'Entity' registered.
MovableObjectFactory for type 'Light' registered.
MovableObjectFactory for type 'BillboardSet' registered.
MovableObjectFactory for type 'ManualObject' registered.
MovableObjectFactory for type 'BillboardChain' registered.
MovableObjectFactory for type 'RibbonTrail' registered.
MovableObjectFactory for type 'StaticGeometry' registered.
*-*-* OGRE Initialising
*-*-* Version 1.12.13 (Rhagorthua)
Error: Cannot open file: plugins.cfg - skipping automatic plugin loading
Программа неожиданно завершилась.
Процесс был завершён принудительно.
/home/dima/dima_project/ogre_example3/ogre_example3 аварийно завершился.
```

Comment: Компиляторы по фирмам и разрядности совпадают?

Comment: Еще вот https://stackoverflow.com/a/4836399/4711135

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**main.cpp**

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QApplication>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**QTOgreWindow.cpp**

```
#include "QTOgreWindow.h"
#if OGRE_VERSION >= ((2 << 16) | (0 << 8) | 0)
#include <Compositor/OgreCompositorManager2.h>
#endif

/*
Note that we pass any supplied QWindow parent to the base QWindow class. This is necessary should we
need to use our class within a container.
*/
QTOgreWindow::QTOgreWindow(QWindow *parent)
        : QWindow(parent)
        , m_update_pending(false)
        , m_animating(false)
        , m_ogreRoot(NULL)
        , m_ogreWindow(NULL)
        , m_ogreCamera(NULL)
        , m_cameraMan(NULL)
{
        setAnimating(true);
        installEventFilter(this);
        m_ogreBackground = Ogre::ColourValue(0.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
}

/*
Upon destruction of the QWindow object we destroy the Ogre3D scene.
*/
QTOgreWindow::~QTOgreWindow()
{
        if (m_cameraMan) delete m_cameraMan;
        delete m_ogreRoot;
}

/*
In case any drawing surface backing stores (QRasterWindow or QOpenGLWindow) of Qt are supplied to this
class in any way we inform Qt that they will be unused.
*/
void QTOgreWindow::render(QPainter *painter)
{
        Q_UNUSED(painter);
}

/*
Our initialization function. Called by our renderNow() function once when the window is first exposed.
*/
void QTOgreWindow::initialize()
{
        /*
        As shown Ogre3D is initialized normally; just like in other documentation.
        */
#ifdef _MSC_VER
        m_ogreRoot = new Ogre::Root(Ogre::String("plugins" OGRE_BUILD_SUFFIX ".cfg"));
#else
        m_ogreRoot = new Ogre::Root(Ogre::String("plugins.cfg"));
#endif
        Ogre::ConfigFile ogreConfig;

        /*

        Commended out for simplicity but should you need to initialize resources you can do so normally.

        ogreConfig.load("resources/resource_configs/resources.cfg");

        Ogre::ConfigFile::SectionIterator seci = ogreConfig.getSectionIterator();
        Ogre::String secName, typeName, archName;
        while (seci.hasMoreElements())
        {
                secName = seci.peekNextKey();
                Ogre::ConfigFile::SettingsMultiMap *settings = seci.getNext();
                Ogre::ConfigFile::SettingsMultiMap::iterator i;
                for (i = settings->begin(); i != settings->end(); ++i)
                {
                        typeName = i->first;
                        archName = i->second;
                        Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::getSingleton().addResourceLocation(
                        archName, typeName, secName);
                }
        }

        */

        const Ogre::RenderSystemList& rsList = m_ogreRoot->getAvailableRenderers();
        Ogre::RenderSystem* rs = rsList[0];

        /*
        This list setup the search order for used render system.
        */
        Ogre::StringVector renderOrder;
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
        renderOrder.push_back("Direct3D9");
        renderOrder.push_back("Direct3D11");
#endif
        renderOrder.push_back("OpenGL");
        renderOrder.push_back("OpenGL 3+");
        for (Ogre::StringVector::iterator iter = renderOrder.begin(); iter != renderOrder.end(); iter++)
        {
                for (Ogre::RenderSystemList::const_iterator it = rsList.begin(); it != rsList.end(); it++)
                {
                        if ((*it)->getName().find(*iter) != Ogre::String::npos)
                        {
                                rs = *it;
                                break;
                        }
                }
                if (rs != NULL) break;
        }
        if (rs == NULL)
        {
                if (!m_ogreRoot->restoreConfig())
                {
//                        if (!m_ogreRoot->showConfigDialog())
//                                OGRE_EXCEPT(Ogre::Exception::ERR_INVALIDPARAMS,
//                                        "Abort render system configuration",
//                                        "QTOgreWindow::initialize");
                }
        }

        /*
        Setting size and VSync on windows will solve a lot of problems
        */
        QString dimensions = QString("%1 x %2").arg(this->width()).arg(this->height());
        rs->setConfigOption("Video Mode", dimensions.toStdString());
        rs->setConfigOption("Full Screen", "No");
        rs->setConfigOption("VSync", "Yes");
        m_ogreRoot->setRenderSystem(rs);
        m_ogreRoot->initialise(false);

        Ogre::NameValuePairList parameters;
        /*
        Flag within the parameters set so that Ogre3D initializes an OpenGL context on it's own.
        */
        if (rs->getName().find("GL") <= rs->getName().size())
                parameters["currentGLContext"] = Ogre::String("false");

        /*
        We need to supply the low level OS window handle to this QWindow so that Ogre3D knows where to draw
        the scene. Below is a cross-platform method on how to do this.
        If you set both options (externalWindowHandle and parentWindowHandle) this code will work with OpenGL
        and DirectX.
        */
#if defined(Q_OS_MAC) || defined(Q_OS_WIN)
        parameters["externalWindowHandle"] = Ogre::StringConverter::toString((size_t)(this->winId()));
        parameters["parentWindowHandle"] = Ogre::StringConverter::toString((size_t)(this->winId()));
#else
        parameters["externalWindowHandle"] = Ogre::StringConverter::toString((unsigned long)(this->winId()));
        parameters["parentWindowHandle"] = Ogre::StringConverter::toString((unsigned long)(this->winId()));
#endif

#if defined(Q_OS_MAC)
        parameters["macAPI"] = "cocoa";
        parameters["macAPICocoaUseNSView"] = "true";
#endif

        /*
        Note below that we supply the creation function for the Ogre3D window the width and height
        from the current QWindow object using the "this" pointer.
        */
        m_ogreWindow = m_ogreRoot->createRenderWindow("QT Window",
                this->width(),
                this->height(),
                false,
                &parameters);
        m_ogreWindow->setVisible(true);

        /*
        The rest of the code in the initialization function is standard Ogre3D scene code. Consult other
        tutorials for specifics.
        */
#if OGRE_VERSION >= ((2 << 16) | (0 << 8) | 0)
        const size_t numThreads = std::max<int>(1, Ogre::PlatformInformation::getNumLogicalCores());
        Ogre::InstancingThreadedCullingMethod threadedCullingMethod = Ogre::INSTANCING_CULLING_SINGLETHREAD;
        if (numThreads > 1)threadedCullingMethod = Ogre::INSTANCING_CULLING_THREADED;
        m_ogreSceneMgr = m_ogreRoot->createSceneManager(Ogre::ST_GENERIC, numThreads, threadedCullingMethod);
#else
        m_ogreSceneMgr = m_ogreRoot->createSceneManager(Ogre::ST_GENERIC);
#endif

        m_ogreCamera = m_ogreSceneMgr->createCamera("MainCamera");
        m_ogreCamera->setPosition(Ogre::Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f));
        m_ogreCamera->lookAt(Ogre::Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -300.0f));
        m_ogreCamera->setNearClipDistance(0.1f);
        m_ogreCamera->setFarClipDistance(200.0f);
        m_cameraMan = new OgreQtBites::SdkQtCameraMan(m_ogreCamera);   // create a default camera controller

#if OGRE_VERSION >= ((2 << 16) | (0 << 8) | 0)
        createCompositor();
#else
        Ogre::Viewport* pViewPort = m_ogreWindow->addViewport(m_ogreCamera);
        pViewPort->setBackgroundColour(m_ogreBackground);
#endif

        m_ogreCamera->setAspectRatio(
                Ogre::Real(m_ogreWindow->getWidth()) / Ogre::Real(m_ogreWindow->getHeight()));
        m_ogreCamera->setAutoAspectRatio(true);

        Ogre::TextureManager::getSingleton().setDefaultNumMipmaps(5);
        Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::getSingleton().initialiseAllResourceGroups();

        createScene();

        m_ogreRoot->addFrameListener(this);
}

void QTOgreWindow::createScene()
{
        /*
        Example scene
        Derive this class for your own purpose and overwite this function to have a working Ogre widget with
        your own content.
        */
        m_ogreSceneMgr->setAmbientLight(Ogre::ColourValue(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f));

#if OGRE_VERSION >= ((2 << 16) | (0 << 8) | 0)
        Ogre::Entity* sphereMesh = m_ogreSceneMgr->createEntity(Ogre::SceneManager::PT_SPHERE);
#else
        Ogre::Entity* sphereMesh = m_ogreSceneMgr->createEntity("mySphere", Ogre::SceneManager::PT_SPHERE);
#endif

        Ogre::SceneNode* childSceneNode = m_ogreSceneMgr->getRootSceneNode()->createChildSceneNode();

        childSceneNode->attachObject(sphereMesh);

        Ogre::MaterialPtr sphereMaterial = Ogre::MaterialManager::getSingleton().create("SphereMaterial",
                Ogre::ResourceGroupManager::DEFAULT_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME, true);

        sphereMaterial->getTechnique(0)->getPass(0)->setAmbient(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
        sphereMaterial->getTechnique(0)->getPass(0)->setDiffuse(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
        sphereMaterial->getTechnique(0)->getPass(0)->setSpecular(0.9f, 0.9f, 0.9f, 1.0f);
        //sphereMaterial->setAmbient(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.5f);
        //sphereMaterial->setSelfIllumination(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.1f);

        sphereMesh->setMaterialName("SphereMaterial");
        childSceneNode->setPosition(Ogre::Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
        childSceneNode->setScale(Ogre::Vector3(0.01f, 0.01f, 0.01f)); // Radius, in theory.

#if OGRE_VERSION >= ((2 << 16) | (0 << 8) | 0)
        Ogre::SceneNode* pLightNode = m_ogreSceneMgr->getRootSceneNode()->createChildSceneNode();
        Ogre::Light* light = m_ogreSceneMgr->createLight();
        pLightNode->attachObject(light);
        pLightNode->setPosition(20.0f, 80.0f, 50.0f);
#else
        Ogre::Light* light = m_ogreSceneMgr->createLight("MainLight");
        light->setPosition(20.0f, 80.0f, 50.0f);
#endif
}

#if OGRE_VERSION >= ((2 << 16) | (0 << 8) | 0)
void QTOgreWindow::createCompositor()
{
        /*
        Example compositor
        Derive this class for your own purpose and overwite this function to have a working Ogre
        widget with your own compositor.
        */
        Ogre::CompositorManager2* compMan = m_ogreRoot->getCompositorManager2();
        const Ogre::String workspaceName = "default scene workspace";
        const Ogre::IdString workspaceNameHash = workspaceName;
        compMan->createBasicWorkspaceDef(workspaceName, m_ogreBackground);
        compMan->addWorkspace(m_ogreSceneMgr, m_ogreWindow, m_ogreCamera, workspaceNameHash, true);
}
#endif

void QTOgreWindow::render()
{
        /*
        How we tied in the render function for OGre3D with QWindow's render function. This is what gets call
        repeatedly. Note that we don't call this function directly; rather we use the renderNow() function
        to call this method as we don't want to render the Ogre3D scene unless everything is set up first.
        That is what renderNow() does.

        Theoretically you can have one function that does this check but from my experience it seems better
        to keep things separate and keep the render function as simple as possible.
        */
//        Ogre::WindowEventUtilities::messagePump();
        m_ogreRoot->renderOneFrame();
}

void QTOgreWindow::renderLater()
{
        /*
        This function forces QWindow to keep rendering. Omitting this causes the renderNow() function to
        only get called when the window is resized, moved, etc. as opposed to all of the time; which is
        generally what we need.
        */
        if (!m_update_pending)
        {
                m_update_pending = true;
                QApplication::postEvent(this, new QEvent(QEvent::UpdateRequest));
        }
}

bool QTOgreWindow::event(QEvent *event)
{
        /*
        QWindow's "message pump". The base method that handles all QWindow events. As you will see there
        are other methods that actually process the keyboard/other events of Qt and the underlying OS.

        Note that we call the renderNow() function which checks to see if everything is initialized, etc.
        before calling the render() function.
        */

        switch (event->type())
        {
        case QEvent::UpdateRequest:
                m_update_pending = false;
                renderNow();
                return true;

        default:
                return QWindow::event(event);
        }
}

/*
Called after the QWindow is reopened or when the QWindow is first opened.
*/
void QTOgreWindow::exposeEvent(QExposeEvent *event)
{
        Q_UNUSED(event);

        if (isExposed())
                renderNow();
}

/*
The renderNow() function calls the initialize() function when needed and if the QWindow is already
initialized and prepped calls the render() method.
*/
void QTOgreWindow::renderNow()
{
        if (!isExposed())
                return;

        if (m_ogreRoot == NULL)
        {
                initialize();
        }

        render();

        if (m_animating)
        renderLater();
}

/*
Our event filter; handles the resizing of the QWindow. When the size of the QWindow changes note the
call to the Ogre3D window and camera. This keeps the Ogre3D scene looking correct.
*/
bool QTOgreWindow::eventFilter(QObject *target, QEvent *event)
{
        if (target == this)
        {
                if (event->type() == QEvent::Resize)
                {
                        if (isExposed() && m_ogreWindow != NULL)
                        {
                                m_ogreWindow->resize(this->width(), this->height());
                        }
                }
        }

        return false;
}

/*
How we handle keyboard and mouse events.
*/
void QTOgreWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent * ev)
{
        if(m_cameraMan)
                m_cameraMan->injectKeyDown(*ev);
}

void QTOgreWindow::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent * ev)
{
        if(m_cameraMan)
                m_cameraMan->injectKeyUp(*ev);
}

void QTOgreWindow::mouseMoveEvent( QMouseEvent* e )
{
        static int lastX = e->x();
        static int lastY = e->y();
        int relX = e->x() - lastX;
        int relY = e->y() - lastY;
        lastX = e->x();
        lastY = e->y();

        if(m_cameraMan && (e->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton))
                m_cameraMan->injectMouseMove(relX, relY);
}

void QTOgreWindow::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *e)
{
        if(m_cameraMan)
                m_cameraMan->injectWheelMove(*e);
}

void QTOgreWindow::mousePressEvent( QMouseEvent* e )
{
        if(m_cameraMan)
                m_cameraMan->injectMouseDown(*e);
}

void QTOgreWindow::mouseReleaseEvent( QMouseEvent* e )
{
        if(m_cameraMan)
                m_cameraMan->injectMouseUp(*e);

        QPoint pos = e->pos();
        Ogre::Ray mouseRay = m_ogreCamera->getCameraToViewportRay(
                (Ogre::Real)pos.x() / m_ogreWindow->getWidth(),
                (Ogre::Real)pos.y() / m_ogreWindow->getHeight());
        Ogre::RaySceneQuery* pSceneQuery = m_ogreSceneMgr->createRayQuery(mouseRay);
        pSceneQuery->setSortByDistance(true);
        Ogre::RaySceneQueryResult vResult = pSceneQuery->execute();
        for (size_t ui = 0; ui < vResult.size(); ui++)
        {
                if (vResult[ui].movable)
                {
                        if (vResult[ui].movable->getMovableType().compare("Entity") == 0)
                        {
                                emit entitySelected((Ogre::Entity*)vResult[ui].movable);
                        }
                }
        }
        m_ogreSceneMgr->destroyQuery(pSceneQuery);
}

/*
Function to keep track of when we should and shouldn't redraw the window; we wouldn't want to do
rendering when the QWindow is minimized. This takes care of those scenarios.
*/
void QTOgreWindow::setAnimating(bool animating)
{
        m_animating = animating;

        if (animating)
                renderLater();
}

bool QTOgreWindow::frameRenderingQueued(const Ogre::FrameEvent& evt)
{
        m_cameraMan->frameRenderingQueued(evt);
        return true;
}

void QTOgreWindow::log(Ogre::String msg)
{
        if(Ogre::LogManager::getSingletonPtr() != NULL) Ogre::LogManager::getSingletonPtr()->logMessage(msg);
}

void QTOgreWindow::log(QString msg)
{
        log(Ogre::String(msg.toStdString().c_str()));
}
```

**widget.cpp**

```
#include "widget.h"


Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    QTOgreWindow * ogreWindow = new QTOgreWindow ();
    ogreWindow->show ();
}

Widget::~Widget()
{

}
```

**plugin.cfg**

```
# Defines plugins to load

# Define plugin folder
PluginFolder=/usr/local/lib/OGRE

# Define plugins
# Plugin=RenderSystem_Direct3D9
# Plugin=RenderSystem_Direct3D11
 Plugin=RenderSystem_GL
 Plugin=RenderSystem_GL3Plus
 Plugin=RenderSystem_GLES2
# Plugin=RenderSystem_Metal
# Plugin=RenderSystem_Tiny
 Plugin=Plugin_ParticleFX
 Plugin=Plugin_BSPSceneManager
# Plugin=Plugin_CgProgramManager
 Plugin=Codec_EXR
 Plugin=Codec_STBI
# Plugin=Codec_FreeImage
 Plugin=Plugin_PCZSceneManager
 Plugin=Plugin_OctreeZone
 Plugin=Plugin_OctreeSceneManager
 Plugin=Plugin_DotScene
# Plugin=Codec_Assimp
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Увы не смог запихнуть в один ответ но, я не могу зайти в гитлаб и гитхаб решил так выложить

Answer (score -1):

Это мой рабочий пример , у меня работает :3  (ogre 1.12.13, qt5.11, astra linux smolensk )

**ogre_example3**

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2021-12-07T15:27:56
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = ogre_example3
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        widget.cpp \
    QTOgreWindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
        widget.h \
    QTOgreWindow.h \
    SdkQtCameraMan.h

DISTFILES += \
    plugins.cfg


INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/OGRE/ \
                /home/dima/ogre/ogre-1.12.13/Components/Bites/include \
                /home/dima/ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include            \
                /usr/local/include/OGRE/RTShaderSystem                \
                /usr/local/include/OGRE/Overlay                       \
                /home/dima/ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/inst/bin



# -- из папки сборки все библы

#unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/lib/ -lOgreBites

#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include

#unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/lib/ -lOgreBitesQt

#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include

#unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/lib/ -lOgreGLSupport

#unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/lib/ -lOgreMain

#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include

#unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/lib/ -lOgreMeshLodGenerator

#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include

#unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/lib/ -lOgreOverlay

#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include

#unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/lib/ -lOgrePaging

#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include

#unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/lib/ -lOgreProperty

#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include

#unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/lib/ -lOgreRTShaderSystem

#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include

#unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/lib/ -lOgreTerrain

#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include

#unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/lib/ -lOgreVolume

#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include

## - a
#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include

#unix:!macx: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/lib/libOgreGLSupport.a


#unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/OgreMain/ -lOgreMain_pch_dephelp

#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/OgreMain
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/OgreMain

#unix:!macx: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/OgreMain/libOgreMain_pch_dephelp.a

#unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/Dependencies/lib/ -lfreetype

#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/Dependencies/include
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/Dependencies/include

#unix:!macx: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/Dependencies/lib/libfreetype.a

#unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/Dependencies/lib/ -lpugixml

#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/Dependencies/include
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/Dependencies/include

#unix:!macx: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/Dependencies/lib/libpugixml.a

#unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/Dependencies/lib/ -lzzip

#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/Dependencies/include
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/Dependencies/include

#unix:!macx: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/Dependencies/lib/libzzip.a



unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -lOgreBites

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include


unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -lOgreBitesQt

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -lOgreMain

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -lOgreMeshLodGenerator

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -lOgreOverlay

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -lOgrePaging

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -lOgreProperty

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -lOgreRTShaderSystem

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -lOgreTerrain

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -lOgreVolume

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -lOpenThreads

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -losg

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -losgAnimation

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -losgDB

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -losgFX

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -losgGA

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -losgManipulator

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -losgParticle

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -losgPresentation

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -losgShadow

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -losgSim

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -losgTerrain

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -losgText

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -losgUI

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -losgUtil

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -losgViewer

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -losgVolume

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -losgWidget

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
```

**QTOgreWindow.h**

```
#ifndef QTOGREWINDOW_H
#define QTOGREWINDOW_H

/*
Qt headers
*/
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtGui/QKeyEvent>
#include <QtGui/QWindow>

/*
Ogre3D header
*/
#include <Ogre.h>

/*
Changed SdkCameraMan implementation to work with QKeyEvent, QMouseEvent, QWheelEvent
*/
#include "SdkQtCameraMan.h"

/*
With the headers included we now need to inherit from QWindow.
*/
class QTOgreWindow : public QWindow, public Ogre::FrameListener
{
        /*
        A QWindow still inherits from QObject and can have signals/slots; we need to add the appropriate
        Q_OBJECT keyword so that Qt's intermediate compiler can do the necessary wireup between our class
        and the rest of Qt.
        */
        Q_OBJECT

public:
        explicit QTOgreWindow(QWindow *parent = NULL);
        ~QTOgreWindow();

        /*
        We declare these methods virtual to allow for further inheritance.
        */
        virtual void render(QPainter *painter);
        virtual void render();
        virtual void initialize();
        virtual void createScene();
#if OGRE_VERSION >= ((2 << 16) | (0 << 8) | 0)
        virtual void createCompositor();
#endif

        void setAnimating(bool animating);

public slots:

        virtual void renderLater();
        virtual void renderNow();

        /*
        We use an event filter to be able to capture keyboard/mouse events. More on this later.
        */
        virtual bool eventFilter(QObject *target, QEvent *event);

signals:
        /*
        Event for clicking on an entity.
        */
        void entitySelected(Ogre::Entity* entity);

protected:
        /*
        Ogre3D pointers added here. Useful to have the pointers here for use by the window later.
        */
        Ogre::Root* m_ogreRoot;
        Ogre::RenderWindow* m_ogreWindow;
        Ogre::SceneManager* m_ogreSceneMgr;
        Ogre::Camera* m_ogreCamera;
        Ogre::ColourValue m_ogreBackground;
        OgreQtBites::SdkQtCameraMan* m_cameraMan;

        bool m_update_pending;
        bool m_animating;

        /*
        The below methods are what is actually fired when they keys on the keyboard are hit.
        Similar events are fired when the mouse is pressed or other events occur.
        */
        virtual void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent * ev);
        virtual void keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent * ev);
        virtual void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* e);
        virtual void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent* e);
        virtual void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* e);
        virtual void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* e);
        virtual void exposeEvent(QExposeEvent *event);
        virtual bool event(QEvent *event);

        /*
        FrameListener method
        */
        virtual bool frameRenderingQueued(const Ogre::FrameEvent& evt);

        /*
        Write log messages to Ogre log
        */
        void log(Ogre::String msg);
        void log(QString msg);
};

#endif // QTOGREWINDOW_H
```

**SdkQtCameraMan.h**

```
// File modified to change OIS to Qt KeyEvents
#ifndef __SdkQtCameraMan_H__
#define __SdkQtCameraMan_H__

#include "OgreCamera.h"
#include "OgreSceneNode.h"
#include "OgreFrameListener.h"
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QMouseEvent>

// enum CameraStyle should be in other namespace than OgreBites::CameraStyle
namespace OgreQtBites
{
    enum CameraStyle   // enumerator values for different styles of camera movement
    {
        CS_FREELOOK,
        CS_ORBIT,
        CS_MANUAL
    };

    /*=============================================================================
    | Utility class for controlling the camera in samples.
    =============================================================================*/
    class SdkQtCameraMan
    {
    public:
        SdkQtCameraMan(Ogre::Camera* cam)
        : mCamera(0)
        , mTarget(0)
        , mOrbiting(false)
        , mZooming(false)
        , mTopSpeed(150)
        , mVelocity(Ogre::Vector3::ZERO)
        , mGoingForward(false)
        , mGoingBack(false)
        , mGoingLeft(false)
        , mGoingRight(false)
        , mGoingUp(false)
        , mGoingDown(false)
        , mFastMove(false)
        {

            setCamera(cam);
            setStyle(CS_FREELOOK);
        }

        virtual ~SdkQtCameraMan() {}

        /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Swaps the camera on our camera man for another camera.
        -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        virtual void setCamera(Ogre::Camera* cam)
        {
            mCamera = cam;
        }

        virtual Ogre::Camera* getCamera()
        {
            return mCamera;
        }

        /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Sets the target we will revolve around. Only applies for orbit style.
        -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        virtual void setTarget(Ogre::SceneNode* target)
        {
            if (target != mTarget)
            {
                mTarget = target;
                if(target)
                {
                    setYawPitchDist(Ogre::Degree(0), Ogre::Degree(15), 150);
                    mCamera->setAutoTracking(true, mTarget);
                }
                else
                {
                    mCamera->setAutoTracking(false);
                }

            }


        }

        virtual Ogre::SceneNode* getTarget()
        {
            return mTarget;
        }

        /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Sets the spatial offset from the target. Only applies for orbit style.
        -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        virtual void setYawPitchDist(Ogre::Radian yaw, Ogre::Radian pitch, Ogre::Real dist)
        {
            mCamera->setPosition(mTarget->_getDerivedPosition());
            mCamera->setOrientation(mTarget->_getDerivedOrientation());
            mCamera->yaw(yaw);
            mCamera->pitch(-pitch);
            mCamera->moveRelative(Ogre::Vector3(0, 0, dist));
        }

        /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Sets the camera's top speed. Only applies for free-look style.
        -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        virtual void setTopSpeed(Ogre::Real topSpeed)
        {
            mTopSpeed = topSpeed;
        }

        virtual Ogre::Real getTopSpeed()
        {
            return mTopSpeed;
        }

        /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Sets the movement style of our camera man.
        -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        virtual void setStyle(CameraStyle style)
        {
            if (mStyle != CS_ORBIT && style == CS_ORBIT)
            {
                setTarget(mTarget ? mTarget : mCamera->getSceneManager()->getRootSceneNode());
                mCamera->setFixedYawAxis(true);
                manualStop();
                setYawPitchDist(Ogre::Degree(0), Ogre::Degree(15), 150);
            }
            else if (mStyle != CS_FREELOOK && style == CS_FREELOOK)
            {
                mCamera->setAutoTracking(false);
                mCamera->setFixedYawAxis(true);
            }
            else if (mStyle != CS_MANUAL && style == CS_MANUAL)
            {
                mCamera->setAutoTracking(false);
                manualStop();
            }
            mStyle = style;

        }

        virtual CameraStyle getStyle()
        {
            return mStyle;
        }

        /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Manually stops the camera when in free-look mode.
        -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        virtual void manualStop()
        {
            if (mStyle == CS_FREELOOK)
            {
                mGoingForward = false;
                mGoingBack = false;
                mGoingLeft = false;
                mGoingRight = false;
                mGoingUp = false;
                mGoingDown = false;
                mVelocity = Ogre::Vector3::ZERO;
            }
        }

        virtual bool frameRenderingQueued(const Ogre::FrameEvent& evt)
        {
            if (mStyle == CS_FREELOOK)
            {
                // build our acceleration vector based on keyboard input composite
                Ogre::Vector3 accel = Ogre::Vector3::ZERO;
                if (mGoingForward) accel += mCamera->getDirection();
                if (mGoingBack) accel -= mCamera->getDirection();
                if (mGoingRight) accel += mCamera->getRight();
                if (mGoingLeft) accel -= mCamera->getRight();
                if (mGoingUp) accel += mCamera->getUp();
                if (mGoingDown) accel -= mCamera->getUp();

                // if accelerating, try to reach top speed in a certain time
                Ogre::Real topSpeed = mFastMove ? mTopSpeed * 20 : mTopSpeed;
                if (accel.squaredLength() != 0)
                {
                    accel.normalise();
                    mVelocity += accel * topSpeed * evt.timeSinceLastFrame * 10;
                }
                // if not accelerating, try to stop in a certain time
                else mVelocity -= mVelocity * evt.timeSinceLastFrame * 10;

                Ogre::Real tooSmall = std::numeric_limits<Ogre::Real>::epsilon();

                // keep camera velocity below top speed and above epsilon
                if (mVelocity.squaredLength() > topSpeed * topSpeed)
                {
                    mVelocity.normalise();
                    mVelocity *= topSpeed;
                }
                else if (mVelocity.squaredLength() < tooSmall * tooSmall)
                    mVelocity = Ogre::Vector3::ZERO;

                if (mVelocity != Ogre::Vector3::ZERO) mCamera->move(mVelocity * evt.timeSinceLastFrame);
            }

            return true;
        }

        /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Processes key presses for free-look style movement.
        -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        virtual void injectKeyDown(const QKeyEvent& evt)
        {
            if (mStyle == CS_FREELOOK)
            {
                if (evt.key() == Qt::Key_W || evt.key() == Qt::Key_Up) mGoingForward = true;
                else if (evt.key() == Qt::Key_S || evt.key() == Qt::Key_Down) mGoingBack = true;
                else if (evt.key() == Qt::Key_A || evt.key() == Qt::Key_Left) mGoingLeft = true;
                else if (evt.key() == Qt::Key_D || evt.key() == Qt::Key_Right) mGoingRight = true;
                else if (evt.key() == Qt::Key_PageUp) mGoingUp = true;
                else if (evt.key() == Qt::Key_PageDown) mGoingDown = true;
                else if (evt.key() == Qt::Key_Shift) mFastMove = true;
            }
        }

        /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Processes key releases for free-look style movement.
        -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        virtual void injectKeyUp(const QKeyEvent& evt)
        {
            if (mStyle == CS_FREELOOK)
            {
                if (evt.key() == Qt::Key_W || evt.key() == Qt::Key_Up) mGoingForward = false;
                else if (evt.key() == Qt::Key_S || evt.key() == Qt::Key_Down) mGoingBack = false;
                else if (evt.key() == Qt::Key_A || evt.key() == Qt::Key_Left) mGoingLeft = false;
                else if (evt.key() == Qt::Key_D || evt.key() == Qt::Key_Right) mGoingRight = false;
                else if (evt.key() == Qt::Key_PageUp) mGoingUp = false;
                else if (evt.key() == Qt::Key_PageDown) mGoingDown = false;
                else if (evt.key() == Qt::Key_Shift) mFastMove = false;
            }
        }

        /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Processes mouse movement differently for each style.
        -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        virtual void injectMouseMove(int relX, int relY)
        {
//            static int lastX = evt.x();
//            static int lastY = evt.y();
//            int relX = evt.x() - lastX;
//            int relY = evt.y() - lastY;
//            lastX = evt.x();
//            lastY = evt.y();
            if (mStyle == CS_ORBIT)
            {
                Ogre::Real dist = (mCamera->getPosition() - mTarget->_getDerivedPosition()).length();

                if (mOrbiting)   // yaw around the target, and pitch locally
                {
                    mCamera->setPosition(mTarget->_getDerivedPosition());

                    mCamera->yaw(Ogre::Degree(-relX * 0.025f));
                    mCamera->pitch(Ogre::Degree(-relY * 0.025f));

                    mCamera->moveRelative(Ogre::Vector3(0, 0, dist));

                    // don't let the camera go over the top or around the bottom of the target
                }
                else if (mZooming)  // move the camera toward or away from the target
                {
                    // the further the camera is, the faster it moves
                    mCamera->moveRelative(Ogre::Vector3(0, 0, relY * 0.004f * dist));
                }
            }
            else if (mStyle == CS_FREELOOK)
            {
                mCamera->yaw(Ogre::Degree(-relX * 0.15f));
                mCamera->pitch(Ogre::Degree(-relY * 0.15f));
            }
        }

        /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Processes mouse movement differently for each style.
        -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        virtual void injectWheelMove(const QWheelEvent& evt)
        {
            int relZ = evt.delta();
            if (mStyle == CS_ORBIT)
            {
                Ogre::Real dist = (mCamera->getPosition() - mTarget->_getDerivedPosition()).length();

                if (relZ != 0)  // move the camera toward or away from the target
                {
                    // the further the camera is, the faster it moves
                    mCamera->moveRelative(Ogre::Vector3(0, 0, -relZ * 0.0008f * dist));
                }
            }
        }

        /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Processes mouse presses. Only applies for orbit style.
        | Left button is for orbiting, and right button is for zooming.
        -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        virtual void injectMouseDown(const QMouseEvent& evt)
        {
            if (mStyle == CS_ORBIT)
            {
                if (evt.buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) mOrbiting = true;
                else if (evt.buttons() & Qt::RightButton) mZooming = true;
            }
        }

        /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Processes mouse releases. Only applies for orbit style.
        | Left button is for orbiting, and right button is for zooming.
        -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        virtual void injectMouseUp(const QMouseEvent& evt)
        {
            if (mStyle == CS_ORBIT)
            {
                if (evt.buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) mOrbiting = false;
                else if (evt.buttons() & Qt::RightButton) mZooming = false;
            }
        }

    protected:

        Ogre::Camera* mCamera;
        CameraStyle mStyle;
        Ogre::SceneNode* mTarget;
        bool mOrbiting;
        bool mZooming;
        Ogre::Real mTopSpeed;
        Ogre::Vector3 mVelocity;
        bool mGoingForward;
        bool mGoingBack;
        bool mGoingLeft;
        bool mGoingRight;
        bool mGoingUp;
        bool mGoingDown;
        bool mFastMove;
    };
}

#endif
```

**widget.h**

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include "QTOgreWindow.h"
#include "SdkQtCameraMan.h"


class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```